# Emacs on mac: bind command-v to C-u M-! pbpaste

Tags: macos, emacs, macros

On Mac OS X, I want `cmd-v` to execute `C-u M-! pbpaste`.
I want to do this because it makes pasting a very large amount of text faster.

How can I define that binding in my `.emacs` file?

Comment: The default value on Emacs for OSX of the `interprogram-paste-function` is `x-selection-value`, which is defined within `ns-win.el`.  It is possible to set the value of the aforementioned variable to the function written by Moritz Ulrich (aka the-kenny) in the following gist link:  https://gist.github.com/the-kenny/267162  Your request would effectively lose the functionality of the built-in / default `yank` function that makes use of the universal argument to define cursor placement at the end of the paste.  See the doc-string for `yank`.

Answer (score 1):

if you really, really want to do it simply add this to your .emacs

```
(defun my-pbpaste ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "pbpaste" t)
  )
(global-set-key '[M-v] 'my-pbpaste)
```

Comment: M-v doesn't seem to be the correct key binding for cmd-v (ie. ⌘-v)